# How to get list of files in skydrive/onedrive root directory for iOS's LiveSDK?

Tags: ios, live-sdk

I'm currently using iOS's LiveSDK and I'm trying to get a list of all files including folders in my skydrive/onedrive root directory. The methods I'm currently using are:

```
[self.liveClient getWithPath:@"me/skydrive"
                    delegate:self
                   userState:@"get folder"];


- (void) liveOperationSucceeded:(LiveOperation *)operation{

if ([operation.userState isEqual:@"get folder"]) {
    NSLog(@"folderIdLabel = %@", [operation.result objectForKey:@"id"]);
    NSLog(@"folderNameLabel = %@", [operation.result objectForKey:@"name"]);
    NSLog(@"folderUploadPathLabel = %@", [operation.result objectForKey:@"upload_location"]);
    NSLog(@"folderLinkLabel = %@", [operation.result objectForKey:@"link"]);
    NSLog(@"folderTypeLabel = %@", [operation.result objectForKey:@"type"]);
};
```

}

I'm only able to reach my root folder. How do I get a list of all files inside my root folder and put it inside an NSMutableArray?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get all files in root directory,your code should like this:

```
[self.liveClient getWithPath:@"me/skydrive/files"  // get directory and files in root directory
                delegate:self
               userState:@"get folder"];
```

1.me/skydrive ---- get the metadata of the root directory.

2.me/skydrive/files ---- get the directories and files in the room directory

3.fileid.xxxxxxx/content --- get the data for the file.

My English is pour,so I hope you can understand me.